# The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp"?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, webview, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

I'm facing the problem with WebView for flutter, code editor is not recognizing the WebView it says `The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebView'.`

I have added WebView package which is "**webview_flutter**" by this command `$ flutter pub add webview_flutter`,

**Flutter doctor:**

```
D:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.19.0 on channel stable at D:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision bae5e49bc2 (5 days ago), 2024-02-13 17:46:18 -0800
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: D:\Android Sudio Setup\Installed\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at D:\Android Sudio Setup\Installed
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.82.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 121.0.6167.185
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 121.0.2277.112
    ! Device ZXPRHAJZWSEM9LNN is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

`pubspec.yaml` codes also have problem with `webview_flutter: ^4.7.0` dependency it underline the word `webview` and **says:** `Typo: In word 'webview'`.

I have done almost everything to fix this error/problem but I think it will never go away from computer but I hope I will be get rid of this error with your help.

**Here is complete porject link.**
**Drive:**

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IfRPvrw1fseKM-qrM_bowYyoAU-h5FQM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The typo warning is not related to the error, basically it's shown because "webview" (as a word) is not an English word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from [version 4.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions/4.0.0), the `WebView` widget is removed and its functionality has been split into [`WebViewController`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html) and [`WebViewWidget`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewWidget-class.html). If you had the old implementation of `WebView` in your codebase, follow [this migration guide](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#migrating-from-30-to-40).

Generally, you should now define a controller like this:

```dart
controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
  ..setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
      onProgress: (int progress) {
        // Update loading bar.
      },
      onPageStarted: (String url) {},
      onPageFinished: (String url) {},
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
      onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        }
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    ),
  )
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));
```

Pass the controller to the `WebViewWidget`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Simple Example')),
    body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
  );
}
```

---

References:

- [webview_flutter | Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)